# Can I apply Chernoff bound to an arbitrary positive random variable?

Tags: probability-theory

I have $n$ independent random variables $X_i$. Can I use Chernoff's bound to find a bound on $P(X>\epsilon)$ where $X=\sum_i X_i$?

Assume that I know $E[X_i]$ and $0<X_i<U_i, \forall i$, but I don't know the distribution of $X_i$.

Is there any constraint on $n$? (I don't have any control on $n$. it can be small $n<10$ or large $n>100$.)

[EDIT]
[This][1](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall09/cos521/Handouts/probabilityandcomputing.pdf) was my motivation for choosing Chernoff. In page 1, it discusses using Chernoff's bound for any distribution where $ 0\leq X_i\leq 1$. Later in page 3, it talks about when $X_i>1$. But how can I apply that for my case? and what will be its implication? Is the bound get looser as $U_i$s get larger?

Comment: Assuming $X_i$'s are iid, you can apply Chebychev's inequality to bound:

$$\mathbb{P}\left[ |\frac{1}{n} X - \mathbb{E}[X]| \leq \epsilon \right] \geq \frac{\mathbb{V}[X]}{n\epsilon^2}$$

Comment: Just to clarify, both inequalities should infact be reversed for the above expression to be valid.

Comment: Thanks Dave. But I don't know the variance and the variables are not identically distributed. Actually their mean can be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of [Hoeffding’s inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality). For a tutorial like introduction, please take a look at [Terry Tao's lecture on concentration inequalities](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/03/254a-notes-1-concentration-of-measure/), especially Exercise 4 (Hoeffding’s inequality).

There is no constraint on $n$; as usual, the concentration rate is exponential in terms of $n$.

Comment: Why the formulation of Hoeffding's inequality depends on n but the formulation of Chernoff's inequality is independent of it? is Hoeffding's tighter?

Comment: Also the Hoeffding's inequality bound does not depend on $\mu$ but Chernoff's does. For my case $\frac{U_i}{\mu_i}$ is about 1000 which is much larger than $n$.

Comment: My short answer is "I don't know".  But an implication of your comments is that Hoeffding's inequality is very loose, which is well-known.  I hope you are not using it in non-theoretical work.

Comment: Thanks Taha. Actually I'm using that in practice. Before, people were using Markov inequality which is much looser!